# radio button in datagrid taking different group name?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, radio-button

I have a datagrid whose autogenerated column property is true. Each cell of the grid is bound with a radio button. But radio buttons in different rows are taking different groupname where as all of them are to be in same group. Can anyone resolve this? TIA.

```
int j = 0;
foreach(DataGridItem dgItem in dgPhoto.Items) {
    for (int i = 4; i < dgItem.Cells.Count; i++) {
        RadioButton rad = new RadioButton();
        rad.ID = "Photo_" + j.ToString() + i.ToString();
        rad.Text = priceTxt;
        rad.Attributes.Add("name", "priceGrp");
        dgItem.Cells[i].Controls.Clear();
        dgItem.Cells[i].Controls.Add(rad);
    }
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Use 1.[HTML-RadioButtons](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13050/RadioButtons-inside-a-GridView-control) or 2.[deselect the others on CheckedChange](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113506/Grouped-Radio-Buttons-in-Gridview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Setting the GroupName Property in your code:

Use:

```
rad.GroupName = "priceGrp"
```

Comment: That doesn't work since ASP.NET generates unique groups for every row(what makes sense).